# Oracle Solaris 11 Express: is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

The download for Oracle Solaris 11 Express says the image is for x86. I can't find anything specific on the Oracle documentation site that states if this is 32-bit or 64-bit. Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

x86 is their way of stating it is for both the x86-32 *and* the x86-64 architectures; in other words, it supports both 32-bit and 64-bit in the same install package. According to [this](http://blogs.oracle.com/jimlaurent/entry/video_tutorial_installing_solaris_11), it actually installs both kernels:

> If you choose Solaris, the system will
>   boot the 32-bit kernel.  If you choose
>   Solaris 64-bit, it will choose the
>   64-bit kernel.  Only a single install
>   is required because both the 32 and
>   64-bit kernel are installed.  In fact,
>   you can change this parameter after
>   installing Solaris 11 Express and it
>   will automatically boot the correct
>   kernel.

Answer (score 4):

Both. Solaris 10 and later has both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries. On boot the CPU is detected and a 32-bit or 64-bit kernel is automatically chosen. When you run a program, similar detection occurs as to whether to use the 32-bit or 64-bit (if available) binary.